# POST 403 forbidden CORS response when uploading an image to AWS S3 bucket ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Hello so I am trying to upload images to AWS S3 from my React application using an NPM package called react-s3. I am using an AWS Educate account and have setup the access and secret key correctly. After I select the image and console log the output it gives me a 403 forbidden error as follows.

POST https://shopkartimages.s3.amazonaws.com/ 403 (Forbidden)

```
Response {type: "cors", 
url: "https://shopkartimages.s3.amazonaws.com/", 
redirected: false, 
status: 403, ok: 
false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: "cors"
url: "https://shopkartimages.s3.amazonaws.com/"
__proto__: Response
```

My bucket policy is as follows :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::shopkartimages/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS configuration in S3 is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Comment: Check your access key and secret key which belong role have right permission to this S3 bucket or not.

Comment: Yes bro I have checked both the credentials and they are correct

Comment: can you post console error ?

Comment: I have already posted it above

Comment: Did you fix the problem? @aviboy2006

Comment: No. I haven't fix this. Why 403 Error came 1. Access issue 2. file name has some junk value and signature created at client side is not matching with AWS side. 3. Secrete key and access key doesn't have access to this S3

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::shopkartimages/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your bucket policy only allow `Get` & `List` operations.
And uploading a file is a `PUT` operation.

Comment: Yes i tried putting "s3:Put*" but still get the same 403 forbidden error with the same console log output as I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem with react-s3.  I finally abandoned it in favor of AWS SDK which works fine for me (even in react).  Here's what it took.

First install aws-sdk:

```
$ npm install aws-sdk
```

Then replace whatever you were doing with react-s3 with this:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({ region:region, credentials: new AWS.Credentials(secret_id, secret_access_key)});
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: "2006-03-01", params: { Bucket: bucketName }});

let upload_params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: file.path, Body: file};
let upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({params: upload_params});
let promise = upload.promise();
promise.then(
    function(data){console.log("Successfully uploaded:", file.path);},
    function(err){console.log("Failed to upload", file.name, "with error:", err.message);}
);
```

Here's my CORS stuff from S3 Bucket Permissions:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

Also, public access is blocked and I'm not messing around with custom bucket policies.

Hope this helps someone else dealing with these CORS/S3/react nightmares.